# Get list of an elements using Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, css-selectors, selenide

I am trying to locate an element on a website and get all of the elements. For that, I use Selenide/Selenium. The element what I am looking for is not locatable by one class, so for that I am trying to locate an element with two class (parent and child). With only Selenide, I can easily locate an element using:

`SelenideElement basketIcon = $(By.className("buttons")).$(byClassName("btn-cart"))`

this will give me one element for sure.  But how can I locate an array of an elements?
`List<SelenideElement> productName1 = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.className(""));` but it is not working, also I've tried so: `List<WebElement> productName = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.className("buttons"));` but here how can I add another class to locate an element? `$(byClassName("btn-cart"))`? Or is there another method to do that?

I've also tried using `ElementsCollection elements = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.className(""));` but it is not working...

**EDIT:**
I have a class called "DriverFactory" which is for opening a browser:

```
public static void openBrowser(String browserName, String url) throws Exception {
    
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion(chromeversion).setup();
        Configuration.browser = "Chrome";
        Configuration.startMaximized = true;
        driver.get(url);
    }
```

Another class, where I define locators:

```
public class EE_MonitorCategoryElements extends DriverFactory {


protected static List<WebElement> productName = getWebDriver().findElements(By.id("asddsa"));
}
```

and a Test class:

```
@Test
public void ads() throws Exception {
    DriverFactory.openBrowser("Chrome", "https://google.ge");
}
```

When I added that last one element locator, with "getWebDriver()" and I am trying to run the test, it gives me an error: No tests were bound, and where I delete/comment getWebDriver line, it is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `$$("<cssSelector>")` to get a list (collection) of elements in Selenide.

Answer (score 1):

Is it mandatory for you to use `className` ? why not `xpath` or `cssSelector`

Something like this :

```
List<WebElement> productName = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//button"));
```

and print `size` of `productName` **list** to see if you have all the button available or not.

Comment: hmm, and is there any way to use ElementsCollection like that? Or can I somehow not use xpath ?

Comment: yes there you can use ID, linText, NAME, CSS_SELECTOR or XPATH, it's upto you.

Comment: Maybe this is an another question, but if you can help me something. I am using 3 classes, 1 class is for locating element, 1 class is for opening browser and 1 class is in which are tests. I have created protected static List<WebElement> productName = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//buttons")); but when I execute it, it throws an error saying: "No tests were bound"
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because the return value of "EE_PageObjects.EE_MonitorCategoryElements.getDriver()" is null

Comment: Also, I cant use ElementsCollection too instead of List<WebElement>

Comment: I'm not sure about selenide, but in Selenium whatever I have mentioned should work.

Comment: Can you see my problem where I can not use getWebDriver() method ? I tried a lot of things, but I don't know why web driver is null

Comment: Where are you calling this method I mean in which class ? What does this method contains ? Please share appropriate code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233292/discussion-between-brithwulf-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Dude I'm out for few hours now.. please share the details here or in chat.. once I'm back I'll definitely have a look and respond to you. Thanks

Comment: I've sent you a message in private and edited my question too

Comment: to get the exact element put if block in for each loop, like this : 

for (WebElement element : elements) {
if(element.getText().contains("Your desired text")){
     System.out.println(element.getText());
    //do some stuff here
}}

Comment: I have also used ElementsCollection elements = $$(".someClass)
and then for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++ ) { elements.get(i).ACTION;}

Comment: Absolutely unnecessary to use such a long construction, having $$() at your disposal.